# Too many method references: 107085; max is 65536 after extending MultiDexApplication

Tags: android, android-multidex

```
[2015-07-16 17:32:14 - Loneous] Dx 
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 107085; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

I have this error and I have extended my Application class with MultiDexApplication, but still I am getting this error.

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Also added the attachBaseContext method in my application.

Kindly guide me how to avoid this compilation error and run my app successfully.

Comment: Have you added `multiDexEnabled true` to your grandle file?

Comment: I am using eclipse, and I have application class which extends MultiDexApplication. Other than this do i need to do anything in manifest?

Comment: @Scorpion multi-dex feature relies on Gradle plugin, so as far as I know it's not possible to use it with Eclipse. But, to be honest, how did you managed to include more than 100k methods? I would consider removing unnecessary dependencies (libraries), if possible.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev I am using only 1 jar file from Amazon and its having more than 100 k references. Anyways I finally shifted to android studio as there is no choice for me. thank you all for your kind response and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Edit your `manifest.xml` and add a reference to your MultidexApplication class

   ```
   <application android:name="your.package.MyApplicationWhichExtendsMultidex">
   ```
2. Go to your grandle build file and add

   ```
   multiDexEnabled true
   ```

   and a dependency to the multidex support

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
   ```

I don't know how Eclipse handle Android projects, but if it doesn't use Gradle then you need to pass `--multi-dex` option (as the error said) during the build. If you are still using Ant, move to Gradle or Maven.

[I've found for you the official documentation about how to fix this problem](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Answer (score 5):

Multidex should be your last resort here, try obfuscating your code at first so that the signed APK will be slimmer (it will remove methods). After that try and see which 3rd party libs you're using and how many methods they have - you can easily do it via this online tool:

Just drop your APK there.

http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count/

After you have the results, try to figure out if some of the libs you currently use can be replaced with similar libs that have fewer methods.

In Addition:

- set "minifyEnabled=true" in your gradle file.
- If you use the support library the you can reduce the amount of methods in it (it's around 20K (!!)) with gradle 'exclude module' and pick only the modules of the support lib that you actually use.

Anyway 107k method seems a bit too much for any application.